# Vault agent injector doesn't add sidecar containers

Tags: kubernetes, vault

I've installed vault into fresh Kubernetes cluster v.1.25 and trying to deploy app with the following annotation:

> vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'

Injector doesn't add vault container to my app pod and I don't see any new log entries in vault injector pod.

How can I troubleshoot the the injector?

-Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added the annotation in app deployment file

```
  annotations:
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-init-first: "true"
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
    vault.hashicorp.com/tls-skip-verify: "true"
```

Comment: why does this need agent-init-first? I noticed that when I remove this line I can never authenticate to Vault. Can someone please explain to me why this line is necessary? Thanks

Comment: @eljoeyjojo https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/k8s/injector/annotations#vault-hashicorp-com-agent-init-first